# wont selected the right username data

Tags: php, mysqli

Im trying to select the right username but for some reason it keeps selecting the first username in myphpadmin

```
<?php 
if (logged_in() === true) {
    $item = array(
               '<li id="item_0"><a  href="../../index.php">Home</a></li>',
               '<li id="item_1"><a  href="../../music.php" >Music</a></li>',
               '<li id="item_2"><a  href="../../pictures.php">Pictures</a></li>',
               '<li id="item_3"><a href="../../poertry.php">Poertry</a></li>'
            );

    $db->query("SELECT  * FROM `menusort` WHERE '$user_data[username]' 
                        = username");
    $order = $db->get();
    $order = explode(',', $order[0]['data']);

    foreach($order as $key => $value) {
            echo $item[$value];
    };
} else {
    echo '<li><a  href="../../index.php">Home</a></li>
          <li><a  href="../../music.php" >Music</a></li>
          <li><a  href="../../pictures.php">Pictures</a></li>
          <li><a href="../../poertry.php">Poertry</a></li>';
}
?>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to change the where clause and add quotes:

```
"SELECT * FROM `menusort` WHERE username = '".$user_data['username']."'"
```

Comment: @PabloLopez Replace temporarily ``$db->query`` with ``echo``, comment the rest from ``$order = $db->get();`` to the end of ``foreach`` and copy the output...

Answer (score 1):

Improper data to help you!
also query needs to be edited.

```
<?php 
$db->query("SELECT  * FROM `menusort` WHERE `username`='".$user_data[username]"'");
```

assuming username is your column name.
hope it will help you. happy coding!

Answer (score 0):

- **First**: Think about Prepared Statements!
- **Second**: Your where clause is wrong. You compare a column with a value ... Change it to:

  `$db->query("SELECT * FROM menusort WHERE username = '". $user_data['username'] ."'");`